# Fixing a merge conflict in NGit with theirs?

Tags: c#, jgit, ngit

I've been looking around and there's not a lot of clear examples as to how to resolve this. I found [this example on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138659/how-to-merge-in-jgit) for `JGit`, but it doesn't appear to be working for `NGIT`.

I've done:

```
var merge = NG.Merge.MergeStrategy.THEIRS.NewMerger(localRepo);
var obj = new NG.ObjectId[] { localRepo.Resolve("a"), localRepo.Resolve("c") };
merge.Merge(obj);
```

However "a" and "c" resolve to null. So unsurprisingly, the merge fails with a null reference exception.

Any help here would be appreciated!