# How to hard reset from one git branch to other in JGit?

Tags: java, git, bash, jgit

I have two branches one is master and another one level1. Now level1 is the latest I need to hard reset master to level1 normally in git bash I can do that by following command.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git tag old-master-branch 
$ git reset --hard level1
$ git merge -s ours origin/master 
$ git push origin master
```

This one works fine for me. My question is how can I achieve it by using JGit. I have tried it. But I am not able to figure out how to set the source and target branch.

consider a scenario I have cloned a master branch

```java
 Git git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(remote).setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("obuli", "xxxxxx")).setDirectory(gitPath)                    .setNoCheckout(true).call();
```

Now I need to hard reset it to the level1.

```java
git.reset().setMode(ResetType.HARD).call();
```

But here I am not specifying level1 . I dont know how to specify it. and also please say how to provide `git merge -s ours origin/master` in JGit

Comment: Please ask one question per post. For merging branches in JGit see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138659/how-to-merge-in-jgit or - if that doesn't answer your question - post a separate question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default the `ResetCommand` resets to HEAD. To reset to another branch, you need to specify this branch with `setRef()`.

For example:

```java
git.reset().setMode(ResetType.HARD).setRef("refs/heads/level1").call();
```

The above command will let the current branch point to the latest commit of `level1` and checkout its state into the work directory .